# How do I compile a module with different active kernel/kernel-after-reboot versions?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

Let me explain, I updated my kernel but have to recompile the wifi module to work with the new one.

The thing is, I can't reboot and compile, because it's my media server to which I only have access via wifi. I do not want to grab a wire, plug and recompile, so is there a way to compile the module while running X kernel version with Y kernel header/stuff which will kick in the next reboot?

Comment: What distribution is it?  You can compile a new version of the module, you just need to tell it to compile against the new kernel, and install into the new kernels /lib/modules.  How you do this is a bit distro dependent.